# How to use variable when setting makeprg in vim?

Tags: vim

I am creating a method called SetLaunchingComponent which is used to set the makeprg with the variable passed in.This is how the script look like now.

```
function! SetLaunchingComponent(path) 
    set makeprg=$path
endfunction
```

Obviously the function isn't working as i wished. As vim resolve the path environment as the system variable but not a:path. So what should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set a option you should use the following syntax:

```
let &makeprg=a:path
```

Comment: Thanks, i works now. So every time i want to use this function i must type `call SetLaunchingComponent("asdfadfasdfas")`. It seems a little complicate. Is there a method to make me type less?

Comment: I would like to say yes but I can't. Vimscript is the only thing I don't like about Vim :)

Answer (score 0):

```
command! -n=1 SL call SetLanuchingComponent(<arg>)
```

it will make you easy to use the function.